# Upper bound on sum of square of integers

Tags: sums-of-squares

I have $n$ non-negative integers $x_1, \dotsc, x_n$ which satisfy the constraint $\sum x_i = S$

I want to derive a bound on $\sum x_i^2$. An easy bound can be calculated as:

$\sum x_i^2 \le (max_{x_i}) \sum x_i = S^2$

This bound works for non-negative reals. Is there a tighter bound for non-negative integers or is this the best we can do?

Comment: if you take x1=S and x2=x3=...=0, then the sum of square is S^2.

Comment: @Ben That should be an answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the integers are not necessarily distinct, then you can create an upper bound by making all but one of the integers $0$, and make the last integer $S$, which gives you an upper bound of $S^2$. This is the best we can do, as increasing any of the zero integers will get us a lower result by the fact that $(S-n)^2+n^2-S^2=S^2-2Sn+2n^2-S^2=2n(n-S)$, which is negative except at $n=0,S$, at which points the difference between the result and the upper bound is zero.